# Mysql PASSWORD() hash not working correctly

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make a login system. But when I use

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `password` = PASSWORD('notgonnasaythat');
```

It won't display anything... "Zero rows selected".
When I use

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` = 'lalala';
```

It works well.
I'm having the same problem with SHA1() or MD5().

Comment: Just a tip on using login systems... Use prepared statements..

Comment: How do you save passwords?

Comment: refer this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-hashing.html or try this https://alias.io/2010/01/store-passwords-safely-with-php-and-mysql/

Comment: What is that PASSWORD('notgonnasaythat')

Comment: For those asking what `PASSWORD()` is check the docs on [password hashing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-hashing.html)

Comment: @HankyPanky i store passwords in a mysql database, as you see

Comment: Obviously you do, but how do you do that is the question. Are they stored in plain text?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I store them in a VARCHAR and hash them using PASSWORD()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed now!
I stored it in a VARCHAR(32) but 32 wasn't enough to store the encryption. Changed it to 128 and it's working fine now.